# Call ended event for Phonecalltask?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there an event for when a phonecall is made from windows phone, and the call ends? if not is it there another possible way of getting such an event?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. Windows phone SDK is not providing any such API for developers. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Within the Windows Phone SDK calls are currently regarded as "non of your business" as an app developer. You can "launch" a call with PhoneCallTask, but you won't know if the call actually happened, when it ended etc. From your app you will just have to make sure you'll handle the application lifecycle well.